fatal: remote error: CAPTCHA required - BitBucket - Ubuntu - VScode
When trying to pull or push I get this error "fatal: remote error: CAPTCHA required".
I read and tried these threads: StackOverflow Thread 1, StackOverflow Thread 2, StackOverflow Thread 3, Github issue.
I tried logout and login back, with incognito (and without), close all browsers, clear cookies & cache, go to "/login?auth_fallback", ask team leader to see if I'm blocked.
I can log into my account with browser but keep on getting that error when using source control in VScode or terminal.

For anyone who encounter this problem, it was solved by team leader changing captcha required settings from 5 failed attempts to a 100 and then back to 5.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
